# How I can Get value of nth row from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, row

I tried below code

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user`");
$result=mysql_result($sql, 6);
echo $result;
```

It returns the value of first field of 7th row. But Its works fine till 9th row. And after that it returns again from 1 . So anyone please help .. how I can get value of n-th row from mysql.

Thanking You.

sumansjournal@gmail.com

Answer (score 4):

You can specify that from your query too using the [LIMIT](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm) clause:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user` limit 6, 1");
```

This will give you 7th record and thus you can specify any number there.

Comment: How you can sure that Id will flow in a order like 1>2>3>...50>51>...
It can also break order ... then ??

Comment: @SumanBiswas If you delete the first row, the old second row is the new first row. You can't tell me you are asking us to provide you with `WHERE id=6`?

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that you aren't guaranteed the order will be reliable unless you actually define how the rows should be ordered, using an ORDER BY clause. You're probably getting the rows back in the order they were inserted into the table. There's numerous things that can cause this "default order" to change. It's a really bad idea unless you really understand whats going on under the hood.

Here's an example that sorts the records by firstname. This probably isn't a good column to order the rows by, but we don't know enough about your table schema or requirements to suggest one.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user` order by firstname desc limit 6,1");
print_r(mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
```

Comment: Why you are thinking that Id in an order !! If I delete any row it will break the order .. and the errors will come

Answer (score 1):

```
$i=6;     
if (!mysql_data_seek($sql, $i)) {
       echo "Cannot seek to row $i: " . mysql_error() . "\n";
}
```

then use any traditional method like `mysql_fetch_array`